# window.frames returning empty window

Tags: html, frameset

I'm trying to do this in my local machine. It's just plain old `html` file, literally the following:-

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Testing</title>
  </head>
  <frameset framespacing="0" frameborder="0" rows="20px,100%" border="0">
   <frame src="index.html" name="mine_top" frameborder="0" scrolling="no", noresize="1">
   <frame src="index.html" name="mine_inner">
</frameset>
</html>
```

But when I try to access the `frames` in `Chrome console` it's returning me an empty `window object`. I'm trying to access the frames using this:-

```
window.frames["mine_top"] //or
window.frames[0]
```

Neither one returns the `window` object that I'm expecting. And when I try to access the `document` with `window.frames[0].document` it throws me this error.

```
DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin "null" from accessing a cross-origin frame.
```

I'm stomped. I can access `frames` just fine which has same setup like `reddit` does in the same browser but I can't for the life of me make mine work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer. The page has to be served from the server. Looks like you can't access `window.frames` just by opening that file.
I used `node-static` package to serve up the page.